# Show that $ M$ is constant on $[a,b]$ (variational calculus)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^2$ on $[a,b]$ 
and $u$ be a solution for the Euler-lagrange equations for the functional given by $$J(u) = \int F(u(t),\dot{u}(t)).dt, $$

Show that the function $ M$ on $[a,b]$ given by $$M(t)= \dot{u}(t)F_p(u(t),\dot{u}(t))-F(u(t),\dot{u}(t)) $$
is constant on $[a,b]$.

The Euler lagrange equations tell us that $$\frac{d}{dt}F_p = F_u $$
(where $F_u$ is the vector of partial derivatives w.r.t. the first argument, and $F_p$ w.r.t. the second).

Some light on how tot tackle this problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try simply calculating the total derivative of M with respect to t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just calculate, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \dot M(t) &= \ddot u(t) F_p(u(t), \dot u(t)) + \dot u(t)^2 F_{pu}(u(t), \dot u(t)) + \dot u(t)\ddot u(t) F_{pp}(u(t), \dot u(t))\\
   &{} \quad - \dot u(t) F_u(u(t), \dot u(t)) - \ddot u(t)F_p(u(t), \dot u(t))
\end{align*}
In shorter notation (leaving of the arguments $t$, and $u(t), \dot u(t)$) 
$$ \dot M = \ddot uF_p + \dot u^2F_{pu} + \dot u \ddot u F_{pp} - \dot u F_u - \ddot u F_p =\dot u^2F_{pu} + \dot u \ddot u F_{pp} - \dot u F_u $$
On the otherhand $\frac{d}{dt} F_p(u(t), \dot u(t)) = F_u(u(t), \dot u(t))$, that is 
$ F_u = \dot u F_{pu} + \ddot u F_{pp}$, giving
\begin{align*}
  \dot M &=\dot u^2F_{pu} + \dot u \ddot u F_{pp} - \dot u F_u \\
   &= \dot u\cdot (\dot u F_{pu} + \ddot u F_{pp}) - \dot u F_u\\
   &= \dot u F_u - \dot u F_u\\
   &= 0.
\end{align*}
So $M$ is constant.